# Proj and fiber product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $X = \mathbb{P}(V)$, where $V$ is a vector bundle on $S$, a noetherian scheme. $\pi : X \longrightarrow S$. Let $T$ be an $S$-scheme.

I am wondering what the projective bundle of the pullback of $V$ to $T$ is;  in particular, whether $\mathbb{P}(V\otimes O_T) = X\times T$?

Thanks!

Comment: If I am not wrong: yes, it is enough to apply the universal properties of the pull-back and of the projectivation.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I believe you are right. By combining the two universal properties, $X\times T$ appears to satisfy the universal property of $\mathbb{P}(V\otimes O_T)$. I would still be interested in an explanation via the construction of Proj though...